# datepicker and other popups hidden behind modal popup

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I have a jquery popup modal which I am invoking like this

```
function showDialog(clickid,reportid) {
         var clickid=clickid;
         var reportid=reportid;
            reportFilterDialog= $("#reportFilterDialog").modal({
              autoOpen: false,
              draggable: true,
              resizable: true,
              height: 220,
              width: 420,
              zIndex: 1001,
              //modal: true,
              title: 'Populate Report Parameters'

   });
```

In this modal I am having a datepicker invoked on button click.. like this

```
       jQuery(function() {
               jQuery( "#from_date" ).datetimepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                   showSecond: true,
                   timeFormat: 'hh:mm:ss',
                   changeMonth: true,
                   changeYear: true,
                   showOn: "button",
                   zIndex:9999,
                    buttonImage: "/gra/images/icons/fugue/calendar-month.png",
                   buttonImageOnly: true });
       });
```

where from_date is input field id..

I still see that the datepicker pops up behind the modal popup. I have set the z-index of datepicker to be higher that modal, but its not working. I have also set the `.ui-datepicker` z-index to 9999 in the datepicker css and jquery css which had the property. 
Also any other popup invoked from the modal popup loads up behind the modal.. 
How do I fix this issue?

Comment: What's $.modal?  It's not jQuery UI, because that would be $.dialog wouldn't it?  Can you add links to the plugin you're using for that, and datetimepicker (also not jQuery UI I assume).

Comment: yeah ..actually I am using the themeforest constellation template skin and I have a jquery.modal.js for that. I can provide that to you if required. The url for that is http://themeforest.net/item/constellation-complete-admin-skin/116461 The datetimepicker I am using is from http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

Answer (score 7):

My bet would be that this purely got to do only with z-index value. I had a similar issue and the following change in jquery ui css and it worked for me in a modal(note the z-index: 2000 !important- the important was needed else the z-index was getting overrided):

```
.ui-datepicker { width: 17em; padding: .2em .2em 0; display: none; z-index: 2000 !important;}
```

Comment: is the value 2000 necessary or any value greater than modal z-index?

Comment: I tried this but its still not fixed. I actually found some comments on the thems forum regarding this issue. just not cleared with the solution they have suggested.. here is the post: http://themeforest.net/item/constellation-complete-admin-skin/discussion/116461 search for primetechpr

Comment: the z-index can be any value greater than the modal's... if you can use jsfiddle.net to give the code for that working there, I can take a shot at it

Comment: I am using jsfiddle for the first time. How can I give the code through that?

Answer (score 1):

I too faced similar issue once. Setting the z-index didn't work. I tried with the below code.

```
$("#IDofTimePicker").timepicker({
        template: "modal",
        format: 'HH:mm'
    });
```

Setting the template as "modal" worked for me. Hope this helps anyone.